# how to save image on local storage in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am new in angular. I want to store image data on local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("imgData", JSON.stringify(this.files));
```

this saving data but no value.
how do I save please help

Answer (score 0):

I  have something similar to your issue, it could help you.

```
renderPNG(fileName: string) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () = > {
        this.files = reader.result;
        localStorage.setItem('imgData', JSON.stringify(this.files));
    }, false);
    this.files = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('imgData'));
    if (!this.files) {
        this.downloadService.downloadFileSystem(fileName, 'png')
            .subscribe(response = > {
                if (response && response.body.size > 0) {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(response.body);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You could post the solution you have. If it turns out you missed then you can edit it after receiving clarifications

Answer (score 0):

use fetch

```
fetch('http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?60789', {
  headers: {},
}).then((response) => {
   return response.blob();
}).then((blob) => {
  console.log(blob);
}).catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

and save the blob with
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-web

```
await fs.writeFile(this.dirPath + '/' + fileName, blob);
```

read file and get url

```
await fs.readString(this.dirPath + '/' + fileName).then(async (blob: Blob) => {
   if (!!blob) {
     if (blob.type === 'text/html' || blob.type === 'application/octet-stream') {
       await fs.removeFile(this.dirPath + '/' + fileName);
     } else {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     }
   }
 }).catch((err) => {
   throw (err);
 });
```

Reference used in library for IonicFramework https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-media-cache